# What does this blue symbol mean?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have just done a variety of events in the Straits of Devastation with 30-40 random people and upon finishing I noticed that a few of these had a blue symbol above their heads, kind of like an arrow pointing down at a chevon:

[image]

I am assuming that this is something to do with the auto-grouping feature in Guild Wars 2. What does this blue symbol mean? Is this something that is assigned by the game or player assigned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That symbol marks someone as a [Commander](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Squad#Squad_commander) in WvW and PvE. It is obtained by purchasing the [Commander's Compendium](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Commander%27s_Compendium) for 100 gold from a trainer.

As a commander, you are given access to a special set of tools for use in WvW/PvE, from the [Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Squad#Squad_commander):

> - **/squadinfo** will show the names of players in the squad and the amount of supply they are carrying. This command only takes squad
>     members into account.
> - **/supplyinfo** will show the names of adjacent allies and the amount of supply they are carrying. This command is not limited to
>     squad members, but its radius is very small.
> - <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse1</kbd> opens a context menu for adding special order waypoints, to mark locations for attacks, defense, and
>     rally points. These special waypoints are visible to squad members.

The symbol also appears on the in-game map, making it much easier for other players to spot, in most cases, the location of the zerg for their team.